# JobHistory server in Hadoop 2 could not load history file from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Error message looks like this:

```
Could not load history file hdfs://namenodeha:8020/mr-history/tmp/hdfs/job_1392049860497_0005-1392129567754-hdfs-word+count-1392129599308-1-1-SUCCEEDED-default.jhist
```

Actually, I know the answer to the problem. The defaul settings of /mr-history files is:

`hadoop fs -chown -R $MAPRED_USER:$HDFS_USER /mr-history`

But when running a job (under $HDFS_USER), job file is saved to /mr-history/tmp/hdfs under $HDFS_USER:$HDFS_USER and then not accessible to $MAPRED_USER (where JobHistory server is running). After changing the permissions back again the job file can be load.

But it is happening again with every new job. So can someone help me, what is the pernament solution to this, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem.
As a workaround I added the $MAPRED_USER user to the $HDFS_USER group, it helped.

Comment: same problem. How did you add the $MAPRED_USER user to the $HDFS_USER group? what command should i run? Can it be done through Cloudera Manager?